# Prevent Slow Motion h264 Playback using FFME (FFMPEG)

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg

I've implemented FFME (https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement) in a WPF project I'm working on.

This question may also relate to FFMPEG as this is the underlying package used to decode / playback video.

The problem I'm facing is that when playing a H264 video that is too CPU intensive (high resolution / high framerate) instead of stuttering, the playback **speed** is reduced, resulting in a 10 second video becoming 15 seconds long (for example), however playback itself remains fairly smooth.

Does anyone know of any arguments I can supply that would prevent this? (Stuttering is preferable to slow motion).

Thanks

Comment: Based on [this](https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement/issues/3#issuecomment-214514866) comment, maybe using ffplay will be helpful to understand if it is a problem with ffmpeg (it is slow with ffplay too) or a specific problem with FFME (ffplay plays it fine). If it is the second case, maybe you could try [this](https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement/issues/352#issuecomment-477686381) to limit the fps (if that is even acceptable).